# PHP create jpg file | GD library does not work on JPG

Tags: php, jpeg, gd

I am following this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop/)
In the PHP script it uses the GD library to move and save files.
This script is working fine when i am using it on my local WAMP server.
But when I upload it to my hosting on YourHosting it does not, When i use a JPEG or PNG file it works but when I use a .JPG file it does not work.

This is part of the code:

```
$sTempFileNameFirst = TEMPLATEPATH;
$sTempFileNameFirstSrc = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
$sTempFileNameLast = '/cache/' . md5(time().rand());
$sTempFileName = $sTempFileNameFirst . $sTempFileNameLast;
$sTempFileNameSrc = $sTempFileNameFirstSrc . $sTempFileNameLast;

// move uploaded file into cache folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload-image']['tmp_name'], $sTempFileName);

// change file permission to 644
@chmod($sTempFileName, 0644);

if (file_exists($sTempFileName) && filesize($sTempFileName) > 0) {
    $aSize = getimagesize($sTempFileName); // try to obtain image info
if (!$aSize) {
    @unlink($sTempFileName);
    return;
}

// check for image type
switch($aSize[2]) {
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $sExt = '.jpg';
        echo("jpg");
        // create a new image from file
        $vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($sTempFileName);
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $sExt = '.png';
        // create a new image from file
        $vImg = @imagecreatefrompng($sTempFileName);
    break;
    default:
        @unlink($sTempFileName);
        echo("unlink");
    return;
}

echo("before truecolor");

// create a new true color image
$vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight ) or die ("can't open gd stream");
echo("after imagetruecolor");

// copy and resize part of an image with resampling
imagecopyresampled($vDstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, (int)$_POST['x1'], (int)$_POST['y1'], $iWidth, $iHeight, (int)$_POST['width'], (int)$_POST['height']);
echo("after resample");

// define a result image filename
//$sResultFileName = $sTempFileName . $sExt;
$sResultFileNameSrc = $sTempFileNameSrc . $sExt;
echo($sResultFileNameSrc);

// output image to file
imagejpeg($vDstImg, $sResultFileName, $iJpgQuality);
@unlink($sTempFileName);

return $sResultFileNameSrc;
```

As you can see I use echo to see where it works and where it does not. So for JPEG and PNG files every code works, but whenever i use a JPG file the echo before @imagecreatetruecolor works but after does not work. So the problem is that that function does not execute. Also the "or die" part after the function does not work.

What could be the problem? 
PHPINFO() says GD info is enabled and has bundled version(2.1.0)

Comment: It's not a good idea to suppress errors as you may be missing on important information that could help you diagnose what's going on. Don't put the `@` prefix before any function calls and check if there's any warnings/notices thrown.

Comment: The tutorial said that, what does the @ do?

Comment: Based on [PHP error control operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) The `@` sign,  When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored. Maybe you could try a different tutorial. One that advocates the use of `@` (and is 4 years old) is probably not the best source to use.

Comment: Well it worked, it gave an error now. memory limit exceeded. I am trying to up it right now or contact my hosting provider.